# Using `gmail.send` scope with SMTP MSA

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send` does not let me send email using GMail SMTP with this log (I send mail with PHPMail):

```
Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
Connection: opened
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP za2sm18821308wjb.34 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO example.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [94.115.154.79]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO example.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [94.115.154.79]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1tYXJ0aW5AZHp1YmFrLnNrAWF1dGg9QmVhcmVyIHlhMjkuQ2k5TEE0REJCMDdxOGVBVkpGT3FQRGlyQVRhTlBJcWVPb3d5RjdmekY2QTZqcG9Za3hxQjZLZFVzSkVISTdXWjlnAQE=
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 za2sm18821308wjb.34 - gsmtp
SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 za2sm18821308wjb.34 - gsmtp
Connection: closed
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I tried to add all other gmail scopes except full access scope, still did not work. However, it will work when I add full access scope `https://mail.google.com/`. Any idea why? I do not want give my script full access to GMail...

Comment: I realized that SMTP may allow only full access scope. So it is likely I must use other way of using Gmail API to be be able to use other scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The send scope is only documented to work on the Gmail API (HTTP REST interface).  If you want to use SMTP yes, it only accepts the full mail scope.

There is a Google API php client library you can use to handle a lot of this logic. To do this *without using client library* refer to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) if you haven't seen it.

If sending < 5MB can send to
`POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send`

You need to set the following two HTTP headers on your request:

- `Authenication` (oauth2 token)
- `Content-Type`: "application/json"

What you should `POST` is a "message" having a raw field that is base64url encoded, something like (pardon the python pseudo-code):

```
message = {}
message['raw'] = base64.url_encode("To: you\r\nFrom: me\r\nSubject: test\r\n\r\nbody goes here")
httplib.POST(url, json.dumps(message), required_headers)`
```

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. I guess I will stick to PHP mail(). Using ~13MB Google Client Library to send mail feels wrong (rest of project will be around 0.1MB). Will miss it because it would be convenient to have sent mail automatically in Sent folder and send mail using Gmail servers.

Comment: You don't have to use the client library if you don't want to.  It should be pretty easy using php's built-in http+json+base64 libraries.  The hardest part by far is the oauth + email/mime, which is the same either way.  Not too familiar with PHP but it's about 10 lines of code in python.

Comment: I gave Gmail API docs at least 2 hours, but I am still completely lost. I guess all I need is to compose URL with few parameters, encode some, add some IDs and fetch it. But I just can't grasp even where to start. Have link with example or can you write most basic example of that URL?

Comment: Okay, latest edit of your answer really helped. It works for me in `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/` so I just need to find how to regenerate `access token` from `refresh token` and I should be OK. Btw. official docs is useful only after you know what you are doing... I program databases (PHP, MySQL, JavaScript) for 10+ years. I am no superman, but I believe I am well above average programmer, but I was just completely lost in docs. I will finish my script and I will give you example of what I wished to see when I went to docs.

Comment: Yeah the docs definitely don't spell out in one single place exactly what you want to do if you don't want to use the client libraries.  It's likely not that common.  The best source I've found for that is looking through source code of the client library, which yes, is a bit of overhead.  Wrt the refresh -> access token exchange, not sure off the top of my head but I imagine source code for client library or searching for that will surface some Google oauth2 docs on it.

Comment: Hey Eric, this is example (http://pastebin.com/QGd26FTm) what I would wish to see at this page https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send . Of course there is several ways how produce same outcome, but this (in my eyes) is much more idiot-proof so that way more people should understand it.