# SMTP: Could not authenticate with PHPMailer and XOauth2

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, phpmailer

I am stuck, constantly getting this error from PHPMailer:

> "SMTP: Could not Authenticate"

I am using XOAuth2 of PHPMailer. I have tried dump and die on `PHPMailer` object, it shows the details configured correctly. I have matched `refresh token`, `clientId` and `clientSecret` but they are fine too.

My code is like this:

```
$phpMailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpMailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$phpMailer->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$phpMailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$phpMailer->Port = 587;
$phpMailer->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';

$path = base_path().'/Modules/Emails/credentials.json';
$credentials = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true)['web'];

$phpMailer->setOAuth(
  new OAuth(
    [
      'provider' => new Google(
        [
          'clientId' => $credentials['client_id'],
          'clientSecret' => $credentials['client_secret'],
        ]
      ),
      'clientId' => $credentials['client_id'],
      'clientSecret' => $credentials['client_secret'],
      'refreshToken' => $payload->refreshToken,
      'userName' => $payload->from_email,
    ]
  )
);

$phpMailer->setFrom($payload->from_email, "Haider Wain");
$phpMailer->addAddress('haiderwayne.9@gmail.com');
$phpMailer->Subject = 'Test phpmailer';
$phpMailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$phpMailer->msgHTML('hello test');
$phpMailer->AltBody = 'This email is HTML; enable HTML mail if you cannot see it.';
$true = $phpMailer->send();

dd($true);
```

Comment: Does this previous SO post help? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54830314/phpmailer-using-oauth2-gmail-smtp-how-to-prevent-email-from-going-to-sent-fold)

Comment: No, I have problem authenticating with phpMailer, the answer you referred doesn't solve that

Comment: But the code in the previous SO post SUCCESSFULLY sends out email thru XOauth2, did you read it carefully ?

Comment: Show the results of your script running with `$phpMailer->SMTPDebug = 3`, otherwise we can't see what the server is actually saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution after 2 days. SMTP is only accepting full access "mail.google.com" for some reason. Any other scope given is rejected. After finding the solution I googled for why this is happening, and this guy explains a bit:

[Using `gmail.send` scope with SMTP MSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161914/using-gmail-send-scope-with-smtp-msa)